# Changing WordPress search URL

Tags: php, wordpress

this is the code which I'm trying

```
function search_url_rewrite() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        global $opt; if($opt['rewrite_slug_search']){ $search_url = $opt['rewrite_slug_search']; 
        } else { $search_url = 'search'; }
        wp_redirect( home_url( $search_url ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'search_url_rewrite' );
```

the `$search_url` is option from my theme settings panel but there is a problem with the slash when I type test in search box I get searchtest instead of search/test do you have any idea how to get a slash between?

Comment: maybe `wp_redirect( home_url( $search_url ) .'/'. urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );`

Comment: HI jamie thanks I tried that before but it was sending me to a post instead of search results page.

Comment: Do you have a search.php file?

Comment: yes, but if I use `wp_redirect( home_url( '/search/')` without a variable its working fine so I wrote an option in theme settings panel to change directly the slug from there but problem comes when I add variable and when I do your first reply as I told u it sends me to any blog post instead

Comment: As per your comment you've forgotten to add a beginning slash at the start. maybe this `wp_redirect( home_url( '/'.$search_url.'/' ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );`

Comment: You are right its logical but also with this it sends me to an article instead of search results page :). I tried all these methods and I posted here a question because is very strange however thankyou